# jQuery on() only for one combobox in the future?

Tags: jquery, future

I have this bit of code that does not work on future events:

```
$(document).on("change","#cboOne","#cboTwo" , function() {
    alert("okAll");
}
```

but if I separate it ... works fine:

```
$(document).on("change","#cboOne", function() {
    alert("ok1");
}
$(document).on("change","#cboTwo" , function() {
    alert("ok2");
}
```

Why the first way do not works? Any idea? tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API doc: `on` http://api.jquery.com/on/

This should fit your cause `:)`

Try this:

```
$(document).on("change","#cboOne,#cboTwo" , function() {
    alert("okAll");
});
```

Comment: thanks very quikly.. I must wait 12 min check ok. Thanks again

Comment: @IGORALVES All good man! `:)` glad it helped you! **just a little comboless change evend demo here** http://jsfiddle.net/4n6kx/